# Is it possible to view on Cache Worker Role (CacheService) which objects were cached

Tags: caching, azure, memory-profiling, red-gate-ants

I want to monitor which objects store in the cache and in the session when I use cache worker role.

My memory is growing up and I want to figure out the problem. Sounds like I cache something a lot but I can't find exactly what I cached.

I tried Red Gate tool for CacheService in the Cache Worker Role instance but it shows just System class

[image]

Noticed that some class takes a lot of memory and I want to figure out which values are stored in it.

[image]

Please advice

Comment: Please set it as an anser. It may help other guys that it's impossible to do. I will mark it as accepted

Comment: Transferred as an answer, Sergey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. I'm not sure if any 3rd party apps can but there seems no tool or api from MS to expose where objects were cached. I remembered in TechED 2013 or 2012 there's a session that some MS guys shown the location of cached objects through an internal tool but I don't think MS published it.